# jquery form change,click event not recognized by function

Tags: jquery, forms, onclick, onchange

On my form, the click event is not working while I change my input value.

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/RHuYs/3/

```
$('form.form-calculator input').on('change,click', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 0) {
        alert('HELLO');
        this.value=0;
    }
    calc_total();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is `'change click'` whith a white space instead of a coma :)

**Edit**

You have another problem in your fiddle, your listener is nested in your calc_total() function, I edited it and put it in the document ready function. It seems to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.form-calculator input').on('change click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 0) {
            alert('HELLO');
            this.value=0;
        }
        calc_total();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zMAz6/

Comment: ok thanks good spotted but is still not changing the input value on (change click) any idea?

Answer (score 0):

See what are the issues here:

1. you have your `.click()` inside `calc_total()` function, which should be in the `doc ready` handler.
2. Use `==` instead of `===` here because the 3 equal signs mean "equality without type coercion". Using the triple equals, the values must be equal in type as well.

try this:

```
$(function () {
   $('form.form-calculator input').on('change click focus', function () {
      if ($(this).val() == 0) {
        alert('HELLO');
        this.value = 0;
      }
      calc_total();
   });
});
```

#### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHuYs/5/)